# MPMediaItem get EXACT file size

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avassetexportsession, mpmediaitem

There is quite a lot posts out there that shows how to get the ESTIMATED file size of a `MPMediaItem`e. Such methods of using `AVAssetExportSession` gives a file size that is really off from the real size, like a file of 3M shows up as 10M. As there is no way to directly access a `ipod-library://` schemed URL(at least not that I know of), I think I'm stuck with getting the file size indirectly.

I guess that the size is off because I set the preset to M4A when exporting, which may cause some transcoding when exporting, but if I set the preset to Passthrough, even with the `timeRange` set, the estimated size of the exporter will always give me zero.

How should I get the EXACT file size of a MPMediaItem in bytes?

Comment: Why do you need the exact size? Do you need to transcode?

Comment: yeah. estimated size of exporter is 0 is if we use pass through. So what's the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

> As there is no way to directly access a `ipod-library://` schemed URL(at least not that I know of)

So long as the asset is actually a file in the library (i.e. it's not something in the cloud), its asset URL is its `assetURL`. That is as close as you can get to a pointer to the file in storage; remember, you are sandboxed (the system is not going to let you mess about directly inside the directory where the user's songs are stored).

Comment: What are you trying to say?